# Get array from nested array in Python and store it into a separate array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, nested

I need help for my code. I have two arrays, one obtained randomly.

For example:
Let’s say the two arrays are:

`randm` and `r_q`

```
randm = [1 0 1]
r_q = [[3 5 2]
       [5 4 3]
       [5 2 2]]
```

By multiplying the values above and transposing its product, I got:

```
multi_trans_output =   [[3 0 5]
                        [5 0 2]
                        [2 0 2]]
```

What I need to do now is to store the values in `multi_trans_output` into another arrays like:

```
r1 = [3 0 5]
r2 = [5 0 2]
r3 = [2 0 2]
```

Then get their sums:

```
r1_sum = [8]
r2_sum = [7]
r3_sum = [4]
```

So far, my code looks like this:

```
multi_trans_output = populations*r_q_active.T
# loop for storing of values in r(x)
for d in multiplied_output:
.
.
print(r(x))
r(x)_sum = numpy.sum(r(x), axis=1)
```

Any help/suggestion would be very much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the size of the arrays are big, I recommand to use `pandas`. These are standard transformations for this module.

Comment: you want something like this `np.sum(randm*r_q.T,axis=1)`?

Comment: @ShubhamShaswat I want to store the values in multi_trans_output into another array r[i] based on its index. As an example, r1 = multi_trans_output[1]. Afterwards, I will get the sum of the values in r1 and store it in r1_sum.

Comment: @pyOliv I am still new to Python. So far, my searches almost always used numpy that is why I chose it for this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store each rows in a dictionary with their respective name as keys

```
import numpy as np 

# input two matrices 
randm = np.array([1,0,1])
r_q = np.array([[3, 5, 2],[5, 4, 3],[5, 2, 2]])
# This will return dot product 
res = randm*r_q.T


# print resulted matrix
dic_for_arrays = {}
dic_for_sum  = {}
for index,lst in enumerate(res):
    dic_for_arrays['row'+str(index+1)] = lst
    dic_for_sum['row'+str(index+1)] = np.sum(lst)
for i in dic_for_arrays:
    print(f"{i} = {dic_for_arrays[i]} \nsum of {i} = {dic_for_sum[i]}")


# Output:
row1 = [3 0 5] 
sum of row1 = 8
row2 = [5 0 2] 
sum of row2 = 7
row3 = [2 0 2] 
sum of row3 = 4
```

Comment: I tried running this code and it worked perfectly! Thank you so much for your help!